# How to deserialize Kafka message to Avro struct, using eventually libserdes?

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, deserialization, decode, avro

I have several avro shemas and respective codec_traits<> structures. I use libserdes + avro to serialize them through template version of AvroImpl::serialize() method from Serdes.cpp, placed in our code. Making such local template version was easy. But making a template replica of AvroImpl::deserialize() from the same file seems to be problematic.

In the consumer I can get our messages decoded to JSON, but I need them in binary, in our original C++ structures. Second decoding back from JSON is not an acceptable solution.

I see that every avro codec_traits<> structure has decode() method, there is also template decode() method in file specific.hh, but how to get all this working with an initial binary message? The example for JSON output uses avro::GenericDatum to get the result, before decoding it to JSON. Is there a way to translate/deserialize avro::GenericDatum to specific structure, if direct deserialization is not possible?

I prefer the solution to not use C++11 or newer features.

Comment: librdkafka has been working on Avro, last time I looked

Comment: The problem is not librdkafka itself, but libserdes + avro interface.
I would add "libserdes" or "serdes" tag to the question, but currently such tags dont exist and I dont have enough reputation for creating new tags.